# String Char Occurrence

Tags: c

I would like to know how char [] work in C. In my program am trying to find the total number of occurrences of each character given a sentence.

```
int main(void)
{
char sampleInput[] = "Long long nights await ahead";
int n, i, g, h, t, s;
int lengthOfArr = (sizeof(sampleInput)/sizeof(sampleInput[0]));

for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfArr; i++)
{
    if(sampleInput[i] == 'N'|| sampleInput[i] == 'n'){
        n++;
    }
    if(sampleInput[i] == 'I'|| sampleInput[i] == 'i'){
        i++;
    }
    if(sampleInput[i] == 'G'|| sampleInput[i] == 'g'){
        g++;
    }
    if(sampleInput[i] == 'H'|| sampleInput[i] == 'h'){
        h++;
    }
    if(sampleInput[i] == 'T'|| sampleInput[i] == 't'){
        t++;
    }
    if(sampleInput[i] == 'S'|| sampleInput[i] == 's'){
        s++;
    }
}
printf( "N: %d\nI: %d\nG: %d\nH: %d\nT: %d\nS: %d\n", n,i,g,h,t,s);
}
```

I should be able to display the total number of occurrences for each letter. 
However, the output I get are random values.
N: 4194435                                                                                                              I: 1974890477                                                                                                           G: 3604483                                                                                                              H: 2                                                                                                                    T: 4201490                                                                                                              S: 4201596

Comment: Always turn on compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang) and pay attention to them.

Comment: The variables n, i, g, h, t, and s are never initialized.  You should explicitly assign them to zero if you want them to be zero.  eg `int n=0, i=0, ...`

Comment: `switch(sampleInput[i]) { case 'n': case 'N': n++; break; ...`

Answer (score 2):

You never initialized your counter variables so they begin with unspecified values. That explains the weird results. The quickest solution is to initialize your variables when they're defined:

```
int n = 0, i = 0, g = 0, h = 0, t = 0, s = 0;
```

This gives your variables know good initial values.

Answer (score 0):

As you've put in a concerted effort I'm going to throw you a bone. It's not documented in any way, but that is the point for you to look through and discern the logic.

This comment I assume means all the characters, not just n, i, g, h, t and s

> find the total number of occurrences of each character given a sentence.

Program output;

> Result is  [A]= 4 [D]= 1 [E]= 1 [G]= 3 [H]= 2 [I]= 2 [L]= 2 [N]= 3 [O]= 2 [S]= 1 [T]= 2 [W]= 1

```
#include    <stdio.h>

   const char *String = "Long long nights await ahead\n";

int main (void) {
    int pntr = 0, chars[26] = {0};

    do {
        char ch = String[pntr++] & 0x5f;

        if (ch == '\n')
            break;
        else {
            if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
                ch &= 31;
                chars [ch-1]++;
            }
        }

    } while (1);

    printf ("\n\n  Result is\t");

    for (short pntr = 0; pntr < 26; pntr++) {
        if (chars[pntr])
            printf ("[%c]=%d ", pntr + 'A', chars[pntr]);
    }

    printf ("\n\n");    
    return 0;
}
```

Are there things that could have been or should have been done, probably, but that is the point to have sort of a guideline and then understand the logic and see if you can improve upon it.